# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session help needed quick please

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi I am very new to Spring and hibernate. I am trying to build a simple CRUD web application and am getting alot of exceptions. I am following some of the tutorials found online.

following are the files i have.

Employee Details

```
    package com.imaginea.model;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="employees_details")
    public class EmployeeDetails {

        private Integer id;

        private String email;

        private Integer managerId;

        private String userName;

        private String firstName;

        private String lastName;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "id")
        public Integer getId(){
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer value){
            id = value;
        }

        @Column(name="manager_id")
        public Integer getManagerId(){
            return managerId;
        }

        public void setManagerId(Integer value){
            managerId = value;
        }

        @Column(name="email")
        public String getEmail(){
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String value){
            email = value;
        }

        @Column(name="user_name")
        public String getUserName(){
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String value){
            email = userName;
        }

        @Column(name="first_name")
        public String getFirstName(){
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String value){
            firstName = value;
        }

        @Column(name="last_name")
        public String getLastName(){
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String value){
            lastName = value;
        }
    }

EmployeeDetailsDAOImpl.java

package com.imaginea.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.imaginea.model.EmployeeDetails;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDetailsDAOImpl implements EmployeeDetailsDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetailForUserName(String userName) {
        List employees = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM EmployeeDetails ed WHERE ed.userName = '" + userName + "'").list();
        return employees;
    }

    public List<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetailForEmail(String email) {
        List employees = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM EmployeeDetails ed WHERE ed.email = '" + email + "'").list();
        return employees;
    }

    public EmployeeDetails getEmployeeDetails(Integer id){
        System.out.println("in EmployeeDAO getEmployeeDetails");
        System.out.println("in getEmployeeDetails id: " + id.toString());
        System.out.println("in getEmployeeDetails sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(): " + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().toString());
        return (EmployeeDetails)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(EmployeeDetails.class, id);
    }


    public void updateEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(employeeDetails);
    }
}
```

EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl

```
package com.imaginea.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.imaginea.dao.EmployeeDetailsDAO;
import com.imaginea.model.EmployeeDetails;

@Service
public class EmployeeDetailsServiceImpl implements EmployeeDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDetailsDAO employeeDetailsDAO;

    @Transactional
    public List<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetailsForUserName(String userName){
        return employeeDetailsDAO.getEmployeeDetailForUserName(userName);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetailsForEmail(String email){
        return employeeDetailsDAO.getEmployeeDetailForEmail(email);
    }

    @Transactional
    public EmployeeDetails getEmployeeDetails(Integer id) {
        return employeeDetailsDAO.getEmployeeDetails(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails employeeDetails){
        System.out.println("in updateEmployeeDetails");

        employeeDetailsDAO.updateEmployeeDetails(employeeDetails);
        System.out.println("in updateEmployeeDetails called employeeDetailsDAO.updateEmployeeDetails(employeeDetails);");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

    <web-app>
        <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.txt</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>



mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.imaginea.model, com.imaginea.controller, com.imaginea.dao, com.imaginea.services" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/organization" p:username="root"
        p:password="root" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.imaginea.model.LeaveApplication</value>
                <value>com.imaginea.model.EmployeeDetails</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Now when i try to fire employeeDetailsService.getEmployeeDetails(id); i get error

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I have tried manythings and i keep on getting one error or the other. Please help!!!

Comment: Quick Help: session is closed. Try fetching the object before its closed

Comment: try sessionFactory.openSession().load if details already was loaded before or sessionFactory.openSession().get

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` property to `true`.

Something like this:

```
<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
```